# Angular2 component not rendering when data changes

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have a very simple Angular2 component:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-people',
    templateUrl: 'people.component.html'
})
export class PeopleComponent implements OnInit {

    people: any[] = [];

    constructor(private peopleService: PeopleService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.peopleService.getPeople()
            .subscribe(this.extractPeople);
    }

    extractPeople(result: any) {
        this.people = result.people;
    }
}
```

On initialization, I see that `ngOnInit()` is called which calls `peopleService.getPeople()`. I also see the asynchronous return which calls `extractPeople()`. However, even after `this.people` gets updated the component is not re-rendered. Why is this happening? Why is the change not detected?

**Edit**
Here's some related code for additional context:

*people.component.html*

```
<tr class="person-row" *ngFor="let person of people">
    <td class="name">{{person.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

*people.service.ts*

```
getPeople(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
        .get(peopleUrl)
        .map(response => response.json());
}
```

If I `console.log(this.people)` inside `PeopleComponent.extractPeople()`, I correctly get an array of people:

```
[
    {
        id: 11,
        name: "John Smith"
    },
    ...
]
```

However, the component is not re-rendered at this point. The view is still showing the initial value of of the people array which is empty. In fact, if I initialize the array with a couple of hard coded people, they show up correctly on the initial rendering of the component. However this list is not re-rendered when the real http data arrives! It is as if change detection is not triggering at all.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to include your component metadata? Maybe the code for PeopleService, as well.

Comment: Can you please add some more code , atleast the service you are subscribing

Comment: Thanks, Mark, Carlos and Pd Farhad. Please see my edit for more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you need to use **arrow function** to retain `this` at this line:

```
this.peopleService.getPeople()
   .subscribe(this.extractPeople); <=== here
```

This way your code should look like this:

```
this.peopleService.getPeople()
   .subscribe((res) => this.extractPeople(res));
```

More information about using arrow function you can find here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this

Comment: Ouch, that one really hurt! Thanks, @yurzui - you nailed it.